# Is there an R function to subtotals certain rows/columns to easily plot by line or bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sum

I'm trying to sum the totals of each course status by School letter. Is there a function that I can write to group by School and sum totals for each column?

I wrote the function Group by School to get totals for every school but am having a hard time putting it into a visual using ggplot etc.

Dataframe is MathClass with School as a factor and courses as numerics.

```
#Group by School
GroupbySchool <- MathClass %>%
group_by(School) %>%
summarise_all(funs(sum)) 

  School Middling Behind `More Behind` `Very Behind` Completed
  <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A           113    450            73           154       142
2 B            84    201            14            22       125
3 C            11     39             4            12        19
4 D             3      8             2             6         3
5 E            11     56             7            15        27
```

Comment: "How best to plot" is fraught with opinion and such, especially when there isn't a starting point. Have you tried any plots in particular? Have you seen something on the web that looks similar-enough to your kind of data but don't know how to make it?

Comment: I tried to plot using a bar plot and pie chart but getting an error since I was using the GroupbySchool. Is there an easy way to sum each school to plot? Do I need to create separate dfs for each school?

Comment: `group_by` does not translate into `ggplot2` functions, you'll need to do something like `group=School` or `color=School` or `facet_wrap(~ School)`.

Comment: This kind of survey with graduated responses is often called a Likert scale, so you might look up `ggplot` and `Likert` for relevant posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039413/add-labels-to-likert-scale-ggplot-graph and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430259/ggplot2-label-out-of-the-graph-in-likert-scale and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505889/creating-a-stacked-bar-chart-centered-on-zero-using-ggplot/19518070#19518070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to visualize it. First I had to transform the data like so:

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

df2 <- gather(df[, -1], Group, Response) %>%
   cbind(data.frame(School=rep(LETTERS[1:5], 5)), .)
```

Then I used `ggplot` and `geom_bar` to make this:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=School, y=Response, colour = Group, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_bw()
```

Final output:

[image]

Does this do anything like what you're after?

## Note:

I had to change the names for `More Behind` and `Very Behind` to MB and VB as they wouldn't read in properly